# Passing jinja into dynamic HTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, flask, jinja2

I have a website built in flask. One page renders a dynamic list of students from a database. This dynamic list is built from javascript and presented in a table format. I want to be able to click the name of this student and have flask take over by capturing the route. In order to do this I'm thinking the easiest way is to have a url_for() as my href value. That is, something like this

```
<a href="{{url_for('studentSelected', studentObj=studentObj)}}">Student Name</a>
```

My dynamic HTML is written in this way

```
            html += "<tr>"+
                "<td class='align-middle'><input type='checkbox' class='form-check' style='width:50px;height:50px;'></td>"+
                "<td class='align-middle'>"+jinja+"<img src="+path+" onError='StudentImageError("+i+")' id='studentimage"+i+"' height='100'></a></td>"+
                "<td class='align-middle'>"+item.FirstName +" "+item.LastName+"</td>"+
                "<td class='align-middle'></td>"+
                "<td class='align-middle'>0</td>" +
                "<td class='align-middle'>0</td>"+
                "</tr>"
```

the variable jinja is

```
            var jinja = "<a href=\"{{url_for(\'studentSelected\')}}\">"
```

the python app.route is the following

```
@app.route('/studentSelected', methods=['GET','POST'])
def studentSelected():
```

This does not work. The error is

jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected char '\' at 5033

highlighting this code

```
var jinja = "<a href=\"{{url_for(\'studentSelected\')}}\">"
```

my guess is that it is failing on the brackets. What is the proper way to format this so that this is rendered correctly? In addition how can pass an object to my app.route?

Edit: 
the following snippet from javascript produces the string I want called url. I insert url into my dynamic HTML string.

```
            var direct = "/student/"+studentID
            var urlfor = "\{\{url_for('"+direct+"')\}\}"
            var url = "<a href='"+urlfor+"'>"

            html += "<tr>"+
                "<td class='align-middle'><input type='checkbox' class='form-check' style='width:50px;height:50px;'></td>"+
                "<td class='align-middle'>"+url+"<img src="+path+" onError='StudentImageError("+i+")' id='studentimage"+i+"' height='100'></a></td>"+
                "<td class='align-middle'>"+item.FirstName +" "+item.LastName+"</td>"+
                "<td class='align-middle'></td>"+
                "<td class='align-middle'>0</td>" +
                "<td class='align-middle'>0</td>"+
                "</tr>"
```

The problem is when I mouse over this link the link is all wrong. It says "%7B%7Burl_for(" and that's it. This needs to be /student/$studentIDValue$ where $studentIDValue is the value I want to pass to app.route()

Comment: Remove the backslashes on the single quotes, they don't need to be escaped since you used double quotes to begin and terminate the string.

Comment: That didn't work. I'm starting to become convinced the problem lies in the characters {{ and }}. I have the following string concatenation in javascript. var urlfor = "{{url_for('"+direct+"')}}" and this returns an error. It shouldn't but it does. The error is "werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint '"+direct+"'. Did you mean 'register' instead?". I'm thinking the flask engine is seeing this right off the bat and trying to work with it rather than ignoring it as simple string building. If I escape the brackets it works, but the href is useless with escaped characters.